# Google App Engine - Have a percentage of users see version X of app, and a percentage see version Y

Tags: java, google-app-engine

In Google App Engine we can have multiple versions of an app running at the same time.  Our main version's link would be at appid.appspot.com and a different version would be at version.latest.appid.appspot.com.

Say I make a new version, but I only want 10% of my user base to see it for a while, to make sure any problems with it don't affect everyone that uses my site.

How can I do this cleanly?

The obvious way I can think of is that I would send a redirect to the new version for 10% of the users.  But I don't think that is a good solution because then they would be browsing on a different domain and any bookmarks they make won't be valid later.

With normal infrastructure, a proxy that diverts 10% to the new version would be simple.  How could I do this on the app engine though?

I suppose from the main version I could URL fetch the newer version and pass it along to the client, but would that be slow, and might it cause any complications?

Comment: I'm not sure how you would achieve this in java, but the term to look for is 'A/B testing'. There might be frameworks out there that could handle this for you.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing

Comment: Unfortunately the term "A/B testing" is not very Google-friendly... :(

Comment: @Jason: it brings up plenty of relevant results for me.

Comment: I should have been more clear, "app engine a/b testing" just brings up a bunch of results about testing app engine apps. And this feature request: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=108

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's currently no way to do this with App Versions without a reverse proxy in front of your app that sends users to one version or the other. Your best option is probably to integrate the A/B testing support into your code, and switch features on and off based on which group you put a user in.

Answer (score 3):

[GAE/Bingo](https://github.com/kamens/gae_bingo) is a split-testing framework built specifically for App Engine, inspired by [A/Bingo](http://www.bingocardcreator.com/abingo).

It's used in production on khanacademy.org and was developed with a strong focus on performance. ([More](http://bjk5.com/post/10171483254/a-bingo-split-testing-now-on-app-engine-built-for-khan))

Unfortunately, at the moment, it's only available for Python -- but it's open source...